# Emberjs develop a component in isolation with its own routing/states, which can be integrated to main app

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I need to develop a component in ember.

The component logic is somewhat isolated from main application and can be created as a seperate isolated application, with states and routes within the component.

Presently I have root controller of component as 'ApplicationController' to enable routing, the name 'applicationController' looks like hard coded.

Now I have the main application with its 'ApplicationController' + related routing,
and my component with its 'ApplicationController' + related routing. It looks hard to integrate them.

Is there any way to have multiple components like this seperated my namespaces? See comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390720/ember-routing-and-applicationcontroller-used-in-connectoutlet)

So the main concern is a method to develop an ember component with routin/states in isolation, that is easy to integrate back with main application which also has routing/states.

**EDIT**

I have two values in component that is bound to main application that is the only integration. 
Also component routes must come as part of application route once integrated.

```
Eg: #/approuteforcomponent/componentroute/componentroute2/
```

While developing I should be able to do just

```
#/approuteforcomponent  -- shows a page saying component under construction
#/componentroute/componentroute2/
```

That being said, the main issue I have now is about both main application and component using 'ApplicationControler

**UPDATE**

Similar Question

[Does ember.js encourage too many controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637202/does-ember-js-encourage-too-many-controllers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the degree of integration you wish to achieve, back with main application? I mean: is the wanted isolation only related to code structure? or aims to factorized components reuse?

Are main app & component routing *really* unrelated?

You have at least two possible approaches:

- You could setup several ember applications, with possible weak relations between them, but the routing relies on browser's base state, so it does not sounds like it makes sense to have several routers instanciated simultaneously with concurrent location management...
- You also could develop your app with an addons architecture, having addons reopening the main app's routes, and stronger relations between app & addons *(that's what we are doing here where I am working...)*

Comment: I have updated my question, it looks like using an addons architecture be great, thank you so much for your answer :) If it is not too much to ask can you give me an example of using addons architecture, or a small snippet or anything to start with.

Comment: Any possibility that you could suggest some reading with regards to "addons architecture"?