# Widget system with Ember

Tags: ember.js

I want to build an WebApplication with EmberJs. This App should not to be a single App. I want devide it into widgets, witch i individualy can load and plug into the website. The Widgets should have the abitity to communicate to each other and they should all use one data store or data model. How is the best way to manage such a application wth ember. Should i use an Ember.application for every Widget is it better to use a differnt Ember Object??

My Plan is to require every widget by RequireJs and have a central App for managing data and widget communication.

Regards ....
T

Answer (score 1):

*There is already a related question @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/11391923/90741 ...*

You should certainly have a single app namespace, with widgets reopening common classes to enrich app behavior/functionalities.

After that, you can activate (or even load) widgets according to current user's profile.

That's what we are doing here, and it does work very well.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have one core widget defined in your main application... with common methods and properties ... and by reopening the common widget you build your widgets?

Comment: Something like that, indeed. In fact, we have called them 'core' widgets, and they are always available in any user's profile _(By the way, as a bonus, we have no special case in term of profile-based activation / display / ...)_.